# System.Data.DataRowView displayed in every component

Tags: c#

I have components that are bind to a binding source,
when I add a new row in bindingsource by bindingsource.addnew(), all of them display 'System.Data.DataRowView' as text.
what can I do as a solution?

Comment: are they showing proper stuff before adding new row?

Comment: actually I drag my components from datasource panel, and they are automate binded, I didn't any code for binding

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I used ADO type stuff, but I'm guessing that you are binding to the actual DataRowView object, so when it is rendered all you get is a call to ToString(), which is returning the type name. You need to bind to a value within the DataRowView to display a useful value e.g. a column within the DataRowView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set display member property of the controls to some column name in the data row to show that.

Comment: I said before, I dragged them from datasource panel, without any code lines, they are bind. for example text property of textBox is bind automatically